# Git don't use the computer clock to commit

Tags: git, clock, git-commit

I'm wondering if there is a way to **not use** the computer clock when I commit using Git VCS.

Why?
The reason is simple, on one of my computer I use an Ubuntu virtual machine. The fact is that when I **pause** the VM the clock is stopped. When I **run** it again the clock is the same than when I paused it, so basically in the past.

When I commit, I commit in the past, for instance, if I commit right now then the commit will be considered as commited yesterday at 7pm. It mess up my git acting like if I did stuff yesterday instead of today.

What's worse is not a simple commit, but when I merge branches or, worse, when I create a branch it mess up the entire local git config and then if I fix the clock I got strange messages about not found branches or not correct branches. Anyway, I'm looking for a workaround that allows me to keep pause my VM and don't mess git.

Comment: -1 Do your logs use computer clock? Does your file save time correspond to computer clock? I don't see how this is a fault with git, when almost no other program directly uses computer clock, but instead uses the time provided by the OS. You need to correct it at your VM level, not at git level.

Comment: Would it not be better to figure out how to make the VM clock synchronize with the clock on the host machine? Or is there some reason you do not want it to do this?

Comment: I never said that was git fault's! I'm just looking to a workaround to fix my specific use. The whole computer clock is wrong, the displayed time is wrong. I have to recalculate it from internet each time.

Comment: @AasmundEldhuset Yes, I guess that would be better, so what? Run a script ? The fact is that it cannot be a script running when the computer starts, because it doesn't. And the point is that I don't have to do it manually because I'll forget.

Comment: I was thinking that *maybe* there is something like configure the local git to not use the computer clock but the github... Arf no, it's local... SO yeah, I guess synchronize both clocks would be the only solution.

Comment: And you don't want to configure `ntpd` because...?

Comment: Because I don't what `ntpd` is? => google. If I'm here that's obviously because I don't know the solution, I thought that could be fixed by git, looks like it should be done in the VM level. i'm open to suggestions.

Comment: ntpd looks good! I'm not an Ubuntu pro neither, I'll search how run it automatically on start.

Comment: @Vadorequest Git cannot use the time from GitHub (or any other host) because at the time the commits are created *locally*, no interaction with any server happens (that’s the whole point of distributed version control systems!). So just fix your VM.

Comment: @poke Yeah, I remember that while writing an answer but I thought that was possible when I wrote the main question. I installed `ntpd` and I *think* that's working. I'll see next time, hard to be sure, I cannot change the time anymore, maybe because of the daemon.

Comment: @Vadorequest: I don't have much experience with VMs, but this seems like it should be a very standard thing to do. You should post a new question about how to synchronize the clock in the guest OS with the one in the host OS, and specify which VM software and guest OS you are using.

Answer (score 5):

There is an simple answer. Use the environment variables GIT_AUTHOR_DATE and GIT_COMMITTER_DATE or the `--date` option to `commit` as described in the [manual](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit)

```
GIT_COMMITTER_DATE='2014-04-08T13:01:31' GIT_AUTHOR_DATE='2014-04-08T13:01:31' git commit -am'in the future'
```

Comment: Interesting but I won't remember. The point is to do it automatically because I forget to refresh my clock manually and often commit in the past... I guess I just need to fix the OS clock or remember to do it each time.